# Is there a way to sometimes require data from stdin and sometimes not in Java?

Tags: java, pipe, stdin

I am using the code below to read a sql statement from stdin on the command line:

```
    BufferedReader in = null;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String line = null;
    try {
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        while((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line);
        }
    } finally {
        if (in!=null) in.close();
    }
```

My problem is that the application needs to run sometimes with data from stdin, and sometimes not (no piped input).  If there is no input in the above code, `in.readLine()` blocks.  Is there a way to rewrite this code so that it can still run if nothing is piped in?

UPDATE: The application is designed to expect piped data from the command line, not from the keyboard.

Comment: Stdin represents the console.  How do you know if a user is going to type something or not?

Comment: Thanks Peter - updated the question to clarify.

Comment: In that case in.readLine() will only block while waiting for data from the file system. This should be very short (around 10 ms) I your filesystem is quite slow, this can appear to be blocking most of the time, though actually it is process a bit of data and waiting for the disk repeatedly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is any way to check if you will eventually get another line of input. Note that your current code does terminate if the user closes the input stream (e.g., with ^D in a terminal).

`BufferedReader.ready()` checks if there is some data on the stream. Like T.J. mentioned, you might be unlucky and ask for data right before you actually receive it, and your user will be sad because you didn't answer their query.

`Scanner.hasNextLine()` is a blocking operation, so probably not what you're looking for.

You could have the user specify whether or not to read from System.in, for instance by using command line arguments.

Comment: I ended up using BufferedReader.ready() which worked perfectly.  Thanks!

Comment: Expounding on this a bit - I found that this only works properly when input is immediately available to the `BufferedReader`.  When piping in data from a command line tool that queries a database, for instance, `ready()` will immediately return false since it takes several ms for a round trip to the database.  Instead, I had to code a command line argument as you suggested.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`ready`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#ready%28%29) to test whether the stream has data ready. If `ready` returns `false`, the stream didn't have data ready when you called it (it might have received data a microsecond later). If you call `ready` and it returns `true`, you know you can call [`read`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#read%28%29) without blocking. (You may not be able to call `readLine` without blocking, of course.)

Answer (score 1):

Unix utilities that support optionally reading from stdin usually figure out what to do based on their command line. For example, `cat` will read from stdin if no files are named on the command line. You could do something along those lines--add a command-line flag or option or something to indicate whether the program should try to read anything from stdin.

Another approach is to redirect input from /dev/null if there is no input that you want the program to read. In this case, you could read from stdin and get an immediate end-of-file indication. The windows equivalent is to redirect from `NUL`.

If you really need your program to detect whether it can read from stdin without blocking, look at `InputStream.available()`. But if you want to support someone typing in the program's input (or copy-pasting it into a terminal window, say) that the InputStream won't show input as available until the user actually types something.

Comment: also, many unix utils support the "special" input file '-' which means "stdin".

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how your program is run when there is no piped input.  Generally a program will have an open stdin and all you can do is set a timer, wait a certain amount of time for input, and if the timer expires without input, assume there isn't going to be any.  The alternative would be to arrange for the program to be run with stdin closed, in which case you'll get an EOF when you try to read.

To close stdin in unix (including Mac OS) you'd write a bash script to launch your program:

```
#!/bin/bash

exec 0>&- # close stdin

java -jar yourProgram.jar # run your program
```

Of course, if you're launching from the bash command line anyway, you don't need a script:

```
prompt> java -jar yourProgram.jar 0>&-
```

But if your program is being run in a Java EE container, I don't know how you'd close stdin before launch and maybe you can't.

Answer (score 0):

On unix you can check whether `/proc/self/fd/0` points to a file, a pipe or from the console.

```
$ ls -l /proc/self/fd/0
lrwx------ 1 peter peter 64 Apr 25 18:12 /proc/self/fd/0 -> /dev/pts/21
$ ls -l /proc/self/fd/0 < /dev/null
lr-x------ 1 peter peter 64 Apr 25 18:13 /proc/self/fd/0 -> /dev/null
$ echo Hello World | ls -l /proc/self/fd/0 
lr-x------ 1 peter peter 64 Apr 25 18:13 /proc/self/fd/0 -> pipe:[139250355]
```

This will tell you if the input is a file, has been piped or is a terminal.